# Android - Laying out a screen with fixed top and bottom elements in a resolution independent way?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a layout like this

- Button
- MapView
- Button

I want the buttons to be a fixed size & anchored to the top and bottom of the screen respectively. I want the mapview to be in the middle & fill up the space.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LinearLayout with vertical orientation and set Mapview's weight as 1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<WhateveerMapLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```